# VBA Download pdf

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Estou a desenvolver uma macro em excel que através de uma lista de id e senhas no excel faz o login num site e tenta fazer o download de um pdf. Eu consigo fazer o login no site e navegar até ao botão que gera o pfd. O problema é que o botão aciona uma função em javascript que abre o pdf em uma janela nova.

Código do botão

```
<td><input
class="tB" type="button" value="Emitir" onClick="javascript:obterFormulario()">
<br></td>
```

VBA para abrir o pfd:

```
objIE.Navigate "javascript:obterFormulario('','')"
```

Agradeço desde já a quem me puder ajudar.

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. É difícil ajudar sem mais detalhes. Quando vc diz que o problema é que abre em uma nova janela, qual é exatamente a sua dificuldade? Vc não consegue acessar a janela? Também não entendi o trecho de código em VBA. O que vc espera que ele faça?

Comment: bom, por falta de detalhes posso não ter entendido direito qual o seu problema. Mas se o que você quer é disparar o evento que está no botão , pesquise pelo metodo `.FireEvent("event")`

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288276/75104) em que você provavelmente precisa acionar um evento.

Answer (score 0):

Quando a nova página abrir, tente trocar de tela pelos comandos:

```
Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle
driver.switchTo.window(Parent_Window)
```

Desse modo você consegue acessar a nova tela e interagir com o PDF, por exemplo, baixando-o pelo URL criado, usando a função URLDownloadToFile, :

```
URL = objIE.LocationURL
Declare Function URLDownloadToFile _
    Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
    Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
        Dim lngRetVal As Long
        lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
        If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
    End Function
    Sub test()
        DownloadFile URL, "C:\PASTA\EXEMPLO.pdf"
    End Sub
```