# Problemas na execução de código VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Este código clica na aba 'Legislação' preenche um campo com um texto determinado (2º For Each) e clica no botão de busca (3º For Each). O problema é que quando eu executo o código, ele clica na aba e preenche o texto, mas ele zera o campo antes de fazer a pesquisa, e tentei de duas formas diferentes. O que devo fazer?

```
   'Declara função Sleep
If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
End If

Sub CDE_ANEEL()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object, doc1 As Object, doc2 As Object, aba As Object
    Dim sFilename As String, sFilepath As String
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim strData As String
    Dim el

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    sFilename = "CDE.txt"
    sFilepath = "C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Dados MegaWhat\Dados" & "\" & sFilename

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
    IE.Visible = True
    Sleep 2000

        Set doc = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.body
        Set doc1 = doc.getElementsByClassName("inputLegEsq")
        Set doc2 = doc.getElementsByClassName("button_busca")
        Set aba = doc.getElementsByClassName("text-aba")

'clica em aba 'Legislação'

 For Each el In aba
        'Debug.Print el.InnerText
        If el.innerText = "Legislação" Then el.Click
    Next el

    'preenche campo: 'Todos os Campos'

   For Each el In doc1
       'Debug.Print el.Name, el.Value
       If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
       Next el

    'Apertar Botão
    For Each el In doc2
        Debug.Print el.Title, el.onclick
        Debug.Print InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)")
        If InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)") > 0 Then el.Click
    Next el

  ' Apertar o Botão de outra forma

    For Each el In doc2
         If InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)") > 0 Then el.Click
    Next el

   End Sub
```

Comment: Verifique se nesse site, na caixa de texto que você está atualizando ou no botão, tem algum script associado que esteja limpando o valor da caixa.

Comment: Pagotti, tem um Javascript que no texto tem p escrito "autoReset: true". Como não tenho muito conhecimento sobre isso, não sei se é este o prolema nem como resolvê-lo.

Comment: É provável que isso esteja causando esse comportamento. Tente forçar o evento `change` antes de chamar o `click`

Comment: E como eu faço isso?

Comment: Eu não conheço o modelo de objetos DOM do IE via automação como você está usando, mas acredito que seja algo como fazer um `el.Focus` antes de colocar o `value` e um `el.Blur` depois. Pesquisa o [modelo de objetos do IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx) para saber o comandos que pode executar em um elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Código

Você precisa acionar o evento onchange com o seguinte código

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537537/ie-click-not-working-properly-due-to-value-onchange
If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then
    el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
    Set evnt = doc.ownerDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    evnt.initEvent "change", True, True
    el.dispatchEvent evnt
End If
```

Então o código inteiro fica da seguinte maneira:

```
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
Sub CDE_ANEEL()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object, doc1 As Object, doc2 As Object, aba As Object
    Dim el

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
    IE.Visible = True
    EsperaIE IE, 2500
    Set doc = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("frame")(0).contentdocument.body
    Set doc1 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("inputLegEsq")
    Set doc2 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("button_busca")
    
    'Digita no campo de Busca
    For Each el In doc1
        If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then
            el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
            el.InnerText = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
            Set evnt = doc.OwnerDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
            evnt.initEvent "change", True, True
            el.dispatchEvent evnt
        End If
    Next el

    Sleep 5000

    'Apertar Botão
    For Each el In doc2
        If InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)") > 0 Then
            el.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next el


End Sub

Public Sub EsperaIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Código de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.READYSTATE = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```