# Clicar em Botão com VBA

Tags: javascript, vba

Bom dia,

Tenho uma macro que acessa um site, inseri os dados e realiza pesquisa, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que clique no botão "Consultar", alguém poderia ajudar? Segue HTML da pagina e código da macro;

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="check()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Consultar</button>
                            </div>
```

Macro

```
'Carrega os dados de CEP e NUM na página e pesquisa os dados informados
    IE.Document.all("numero-logradouro-ins").Value = lNUM
    IE.Document.all("cep-ins").Value = lCEP
    For Each Button In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("btn btn-primary btn-sm") 'FAILED
Button.Click
    Next
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Veja se você não precisa acionar o evento [onclick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). [A resposta deste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288276/75104) fornece um exemplo para o evento onchange.

Comment: @danieltakeshi acabou que nem precisei chamar evento, como o botão é uma class apenas alterei o getElementTagName para getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-sm") com o nome da class do botão, deu certinho! Obrigado pela atençao, abraços!