# Macros fora do Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, google-chrome

Estou me aventurando pelo mundo da programação, e de começo, estou usando muito VBA na empresa, e está me ajudando muito, tarefas que demorava horas, estou fazendo em poucos segundos utilizando macros!

Trabalho com muita frequencia buscando dados em um site, nesse site existem varios Id's de certos produtos, dependendo da categoria são mais de 500, e preciso buscar o id de cada um deles, esses id's só aparecem quando eu clico no produto, 1 por 1 consegui todos os dados de uma vez, acessando o código html e fazendo filtro, pois todos os códigos, no html, começam com "id=****". sófiltrei no excel e tudo beleza.

Teria como criar uma macro que "automatizasse" o processo de busca?

pois é muito repetitivo e sempre é o mesmo passo, com algumas seleções.

Obrigado!

Comment: Depende do código HTML do site... Muitas vezes algum evento precisa ser acionado, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288276/75104), que aciona o evento onchange.

Comment: Sim, é possível criar macros pra fazer esse tipo de processo.
Pra isso você precisa criar um **objeto HTML** dentro da interface do **VBA**.
Depois disso é similar ao caso de procurar em uma planilha.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, estou buscando as soluções nas quais me indicaram.